# is there default constructor even if i mention constructor in class

Tags: java

```
public class Ex
{ 
  int a;   

  public Ex()   
  {
    System.out.println("a is "+a);   
  } 
}
```

output is:a is 0

where a gets initialized...

i know that default values for int is zero..my question is that where it gets initialied ..through default constructor ?(i heard that default constructor is created when we don't mention any constructor in the class)

Comment: @Qwerky  :yes ..it is duplicate .because i did't get expected answer in the original post..

Comment: @saravanan - OK, it is a duplicate and, believe it or not, darioo gave the best/correct answer. The reason: Java is specified like this.

Comment: @Qwerky, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. It asks about a totally different thing, although the text is virtually the same. "Where are the fields of a class instance are initialized to their default values?" and "Is there a compiler-generated default constructor even if I write one myself?" sound like very different questions to me. The first one is even quite good, really.

Comment: Both posts have *identical* content, how is that not a duplicate?